# Python: convert a 'for' loop into a while loop, but it must meet the len(i) condition within the loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I've been practising switching `for` loops with `while` loops in Python.

My problem is the line under the while loop where I'm trying to check if `i` (a word in the string sentence) is shorter than six characters. With a `for` loop this is easy, because it just iterates over each word in words, so I can use `len(i)`, but in the `while` version `i` is now an int so I what should I do!

`For` loop version:

```
def concatenation(string):
    words = string.split()
    result = ''
    for i in words:
        if len(i) < 6:
            result = result + i
    return result
```

My attempt at a `while` loop:

```
def concatenation(string):
    words = string.split()
    result = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(words):
        if len(words[i]) < 6:
            result += i
            i += 1
    return result
```

Comment: Sorry Craig, I was just editing it to add my i +=1 increment after I submitted it and realised I'd forgotten to put my i increment in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've partly got it already, when you wrote

```
if len(words[i]) < 6:
```

Since `i` is just an index, you can access the elements in the list `words` with `words[index]`, which is how you check the length of that word, and how you can add it to result.

You also need to increase `i` in the while loop, since it doesn't automatically do that for you.

```
>>> def concat_while(string):
        words = string.split()
        result = ""
        i = 0
        while i < len(words):
            if len(words[i]) < 6:
                result += words[i]
            i += 1
        return result
```

Test case:

```
>>> a = "this is a test string, alright yeah?"
>>> concat_while(a)
'thisisatestyeah?'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely get it now - I thought my len(words[i]) was off so it didn't occur to me that the next line where i is needs to be words[i] since I was getting the error message on the line above. Thank you. Yes, sorry about the i incrementer - I realised after I'd submitted that I forgot that part. I got the indent wrong on that too.

Answer (score 2):

`i` never changes in your while loop, so you will never reach the end of it. Regardless in both examples you use `i` in a different context. It is good practice to name variables according to what they stand for. Better examples:

For loop example (interchanged `i` with `word`):

```
def concatenation(string):
    words = string.split()
    result = ''
    for word in words:
        if len(word) < 6:
            result += word
    return result
```

(Corrected) while loop example (interchanged `i` with `words_index`):

```
def concatenation(string):
    words = string.split()
    result = ''
    words_index = 0
    while words_index < len(words):
        word = words[words_index]
        if len(word) < 6:
            result += word
        words_index += 1
    return result
```

Comment: That's a good idea - I usually use "for word in words" for sentence problems, but when I attempted the while loop it seemed odd to call it 'word', but your example using the name words_index makes sense to me now.